# Can I easily skip pixels in Bresenham's line algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graphics, bresenham

I have a program which is using [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to scan pixels in a line. This is reading pixels rather than writing them, and in my particular case, reading them is costly.

I can however determine that some spans of pixels do not need to be read. It looks something like this:

```
Normal scan of all pixels:

*start
 \
  \
   \
    \
     \
      *end

Scan without reading all pixels:

*start
 \
  \
        - At this point I know I can skip (for example) the next 100 pixels
          in the loop. Crucially, I can't know this until I reach the gap.
     \
      *end
```

The gap in the middle is much quicker because I can just iterate over the pixels without reading them.

However, can I modify the loop in any way to just jump directly forward 100 pixels within the loop, calculating directly the required values 100 steps ahead in the line algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Bresenhams middlepoint algorithm calculates 'distance' of point from a theoretical line going from (ax,ay)->(bx,by) by summing up *digital differences* delta_x = (by-ay), delta_y = (ax-bx).

Thus, if one want's to skip 7 pixels, one has to add accum += 7*delta_x; then dividing by delta_y one can check how many pixels should have been moved in y-direction and taking a remainder accum = accum % delta_y one should be able to continue at proper position.

The nice thing is that the algorithm is originated from the necessity of avoiding a division...

*Disclaimer*: whatever told may need to be adjusted by half delta.

Answer (score 0):

Your main loop looks essentially something like:

```
  while (cnt > 0) // cnt is 1 + the biggest of abs(x2-x1) and abs(y2-y1)
  {
    ReadOrWritePixel(x, y);

    k += n; // n is the smallest of abs(x2-x1) and abs(y2-y1)
    if (k < m) // m is the biggest of abs(x2-x1) and abs(y2-y1)
    {
      // continuing a horizontal/vertical segment
      x += dx2; // dx2 = sgn(x2-x1) or 0
      y += dy2; // dy2 = sgn(y2-y1) or 0
    }
    else
    {
      // beginning a new horizontal/vertical segment
      k -= m;
      x += dx1; // dx1 = sgn(x2-x1)
      y += dy1; // dy1 = sgn(y2-y1)
    }

    cnt--;
  }
```

So, skipping some q pixels is equivalent to the following adjustments (unless I made a mistake somewhere):

- cnt<sub>new</sub> = cnt<sub>old</sub> - q
- k<sub>new</sub> = (k<sub>old</sub> + n * q) % m
- x<sub>new</sub> = x<sub>old</sub> + ((k<sub>old</sub> + n * q) / m) * dx1 + (q - ((k<sub>old</sub> + n * q) / m)) * dx2
- y<sub>new</sub> = y<sub>old</sub> + ((k<sub>old</sub> + n * q) / m) * dy1 + (q - ((k<sub>old</sub> + n * q) / m)) * dy2

Note that / and % are integer division and modulo operators.